# iPhone Facebook sample code with oauth

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth

Is there any sample code for iphone to work with facebook using Oauth protocol?

Comment: I would imagine there is a lot but why don't you just search for it with Google? That's all i would do.

Answer (score 0):

The [Facebook iOS SDK on Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) has a fully working sample.  All you need to do is change your appId and it should work.